# A confusing example in *Fourier Analysis an Introduction* pg 87

Tags: limits, fourier-analysis

From *Fourier Analysis an Introduction* pg 87:

"Finally, we need to find a convergent series of positive terms $\sum \alpha_k$ and a sequence of integers {$N_{k}$} which increases  rapidly enough so that:
$$(i)N_{k+1}>3N_{k}$$ $$(ii)\alpha_{k}\log{N_{k}}\to \infty\ \ as\ k\to\infty$$
We choose (for example) $\alpha_{k}=\frac{1}{k^{2}}$ and $N_{k}=3^{2^k}$ which are easily seen to satisfy the above criteria."

I have doubted it if it really satisfies the second condition, Because:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\log{3^{2^{k}}}}{k^2}=\frac{\log{9^{k}}}{k^2}=\frac{k\log{9}}{k^2}=\frac{\log{9}}{k}\to 0$$
or
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\log{3^{2^{k}}}}{k^2}=\frac{\log{3^{k^{2}}}}{k^2}=\frac{k^{2}\log{3}}{k^2}=\log{3}$$
I don't get the example above, it doesn't satisfy the (ii) condition.
Can someone help me with it?

Comment: You have an error in the first condition. How can $N_k>3N_k$?

Comment: Thanks. I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you got it wrong both times. The sequence $N_k=3^{2^k}$ means that you raise 3 to the power of $2^k$, so you can write $N_k = 3^{(2^k)}$.

As for the limit, it does indeed satisfy the conditions because

$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \frac{\log3^{2^k}}{k^2} = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \frac{2^k\log3}{k^2} = +\infty$$

Comment: Thanks, I was getting confused by powers.